# Drawing problem

Tags: windows, forms

I have a panel with a windrose as background image.  I want to draw 16 line arrows representing wind direction (N, NNE, NE, ENE, E, ESE, SE, SSE, S, SSW, SW, WSW, W, WNW, NW, NNW). I want the lines to correspond to the ones on image.  Then I need a click event to fire when a user selects one of the lines (to display monthly wind data represented by each line/wind direction).

Is it possible to do this in C# Windows Form?  I haven't done much drawing programming.  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is possible. You just have to create a subclass of Control, and in the overriden OnPaint function follow your own steps:

- Paint the background.
- Paint the arrows. You'll have to get the coordinates somehow.

Then override the OnMouseDown and/or OnMouseUp functions of your Control to:

- Check if the user clicked any arrow.
- Present the data.